# textview not visible in listview when a button is clicked on a particular row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have an custom `listview` which contains `button` and `textview`. The `textview` visibility is gone. When the `button` text is "email" and if I click on `button` the `textview` should display below the `button`. But the last `textview` is always getting visible.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    wantedUsers du = wusers.get(i);

    final String mcontact = du.mcontact;

    if(view==null) {
        viewholder = new viewholder();
        view = LayoutInflater.from(ws).inflate(R.layout.wantedmoviecustom, null);
         viewholder.mcontwcustom = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.mcontwcustom);

        viewholder.mdisplayemail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mdisplayemail);
        view.setTag(viewholder);
    } else {
        viewholder = (viewholder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(mcontact.contains("@")) {
        viewholder.mcontwcustom.setText("Show Email");
        viewholder.mdisplayemail.setText(mcontact);
    } else {
        viewholder.mcontwcustom.setText("Call");
    }

    viewholder.mcontwcustom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(mcontact.contains("@")) {
                int p=(Integer)view.getTag();

                viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // viewholder.mdisplayemail.setText(mcontact);

            }
            else
            {
                Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + mcontact);
                Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
                ws.startActivity(surf);
            }
        }
    });
    viewholder.mcontwcustom.setTag(i);
    return view;
}
```

below is my `getview` from custom `adapter`. So how can I make a `textview` `visbile` when a `button` clicked on particular row.

Comment: you need to change `viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility();` to `viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Show me your layout ?

Comment: @user2269164 check my answer may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a **Global** variable

```
int positionOfButtonClick = -1;
```

then you need to update your position on `button` click and need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

like - :

```
 viewholder.mcontwcustom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       positionOfButtonClick = i;  
       notifyDataSetChanged();
     //your other code    
});
```

Then, in **getView**

you need to check the position and need to `VISIBLE` your `textView` like -:

```
if(i==positionOfButtonClick ){
viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Now, your **getView** should be-:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

wantedUsers du = wusers.get(i);

final String mcontact = du.mcontact;



if(view==null) {
    viewholder = new viewholder();
    view = LayoutInflater.from(ws).inflate(R.layout.wantedmoviecustom, null);
     viewholder.mcontwcustom = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.mcontwcustom);

    viewholder.mdisplayemail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mdisplayemail);


if(i==positionOfButtonClick ){
viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }


    view.setTag(viewholder);
} else {
    viewholder = (viewholder) view.getTag();
}



if(mcontact.contains("@")) {
    viewholder.mcontwcustom.setText("Show Email");
    viewholder.mdisplayemail.setText(mcontact);
} else {
    viewholder.mcontwcustom.setText("Call");
}

viewholder.mcontwcustom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(mcontact.contains("@")) {
            int p=(Integer)view.getTag();



       positionOfButtonClick = i;  
       notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        else
        {
            Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + mcontact);
            Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
            ws.startActivity(surf);
        }
    }
});
viewholder.mcontwcustom.setTag(i);
return view;
}
```

Comment: @user2269164 try this will help

Answer (score 0):

Change in code as mention below, I think it help you.

```
viewholder.mcontwcustom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(mcontact.contains("@")) {
                int p=(Integer)view.getTag();

               viewholder.mdisplayemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // viewholder.mdisplayemail.setText(mcontact);

            }
```

Comment: @UltimateDevil - It will enable the textview in last row.not the one where i clicked.

Comment: Yes, Wait i am updating answer